# Javascript DOM elements invalid CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, tooltip

I have a tooltip plugin (tooltip.js & tooltip.css). The requirements of this tooltip is that inside a SPAN or DIV element you need to have both rel='tooltip' and title='' - then the tooltip plugin will initate a tooltip.

The problem is that I'm adding DOM HTML elements to the page with those attributes but they are not working. They initially work but when I add dom elements, those DOM elements stop working.

FYI I'm using (Jquery mobile 1.3.1 & jQuery 1.9.1)

HTML

```
<table id='maintable'>

</table>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
//function initiates with this stuff
var part1 = "<tr><td rel='tooltip' title='new title'>Something</td></tr>";
$('#maintable').append(part1).trigger('create');
```

What am i doing wrong? Why is it not initiating?  FYI .trigger('refresh') does not work.

Comment: I'ts not working because the tooltip functionality you're using isn't built to work with dynamic elements. You will have to re-bind to those elements after you append the data, if you want the jQuery functionality to work with them.

Comment: what do you mean by 'rebind'?

Comment: `$('[title]').myTooltip()`

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still not following. So I need to create a function called myTooltip?

Comment: `tooltip.js` <-- what's in this file? how do you bind the tooltip normally? I mean, unless you really just downloaded a file and it handled your tooltips for you, then you're going to be in the dark. Otherwise, you had to invoke it yourself, by doing something like `$('[title]').myTooltip()`. I will not be able to advise moving forward without getting a link to that file.

Comment: I apologize. I see what you mean - unfortunately everything is within a $(document).ready(function(). Here's the script --> [tooltip.js](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=BinGnK58)

Comment: ignore the function tooltipIt(). I created that to test something and forgot to remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
targets.bind( 'mouseenter', function()
```

to

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', targets, function(){
```

And also

```
target.bind( 'mouseleave', remove_tooltip );
tooltip.bind( 'click', remove_tooltip )
```

to

```
$(document).on('mouseleave', target, remove_tooltip);
$(document).on('click', tooltip, remove_tooltip);
```

And replace `document` in my code, with the closest **static ** (never removed or replaced) **parent** element.

This will give event delegation to dynamic elements and will allow for the code to still execute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in jQuery (mobile), but I assume that the tooltip initializes before the DOM Elements are appended. If this is the case you should either append your elements before the tooltip chek the DOM tree, or more dynamically, which is more likely to be the usual use case, re-initialize the tooltips. Anyway I suggest checking the tooltip implementation if possible, to find the easiest, most efficent way to do.